# What is going in this malloc'ed array in Cython?

Tags: python, c, malloc, cython

```
%%cython -f -c=-O3 -c=-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp
from cython.parallel import parallel, prange
from libc.stdlib cimport abort, malloc, free

cdef int idx, i, n = 100
cdef int k
cdef int * local_buf
cdef int size = 10

cdef void func(int* lb) nogil:
    cdef int j
    for j in xrange(size):
        lb[j] += -1*j

local_buf = <int *> malloc(sizeof(int) * size)
with nogil, parallel():

    if local_buf == NULL:
        abort()

    # populate our local buffer in a sequential loop
    for i in xrange(size):
        local_buf[i] = i * 2

    # share the work using the thread-local buffer(s)
    for k in prange(n, schedule='guided'):
        func(local_buf)

for i in xrange(size):
    print local_buf[i]

free(local_buf)

0
-98
-196
-294
-392
-490
-588
-686
-784
-882
```

edit:
The above block shows the output after one run, but the contents in `local_buf` seems to change every or so re-run. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result there seems reasonable with the code given, do you actually get different result each run?

This should be regular python equivalent:

```
size = 10
n = 100

lst = [i*2 for i in range(size)]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(size):
        lst[j] += -1*j
print lst
#[0, -98, -196, -294, -392, -490, -588, -686, -784, -882]
```

Comment: D'OH I am feeling very stupid. Forgot I was within 2 forloops and not one.

Comment: yes, I am getting different answers in almost every run. I just got 0
-97
-194
-291
-380
-475
-570
-665
-760
-873

Comment: @richizy Can you try rerun it with a regular range instead of the parallel range. Maybe the parallalizing is messing something up.

Comment: just tried that. the output is now the same in every run. I suppose it's because I'm running `xrange` within `func`, even though I explicitly said it was `nogil`. Cython doesn't give an error for that case...

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is you're adding to the same element in parallel. `lb[j] += -1*j`. Ideally openmp should handle this by some kind of fancy reduction algorithm, but i guess it's not working in this case.

Comment: @richizy You could rewrite your algorithm so that each parallell thread only accesses one element each, that should run fine in parallell.